# Relationship of QGIS to its sister programs?

Tags: qgis

I'v e been using QGIS 2.4 for a number of months now and we are using it a bit at work.

I noted that when I did the initial install a number of new icons appeared on my desktop namely
MSys
QGIS Desktop 2.4.0
QGIS Browser
Grass
OSGEOWShell
Saga GIS (2.0.8)

If I need to roll this out to other machines I would prefer just to have the minimum footprint. I can see that I probably need the browser as that looks like it is within QGIS Desktop but Grass / OSGeowShell and Saga as well.

I'd be interested if anyone could indicate any interdependencies between the programs and what is the minimum install. I suspect its Desktop and Browser?

Answer (score 3):

SAGA and GRASS in particular are plugins to QGIS (sister programs for which QGIS effectively provides a seamless front end).  Since these are used in the 'Processing' toolbox, I highly recommend them, although QGIS will work quite happily without them... but you loose some of the processing capabilities, especially for raster functions.

If you used osgeo4w and opted for express install, you may also see things like GPSBable, OpenJump and a few others.  These are more like companion programs that are not "part of" QGIS like SAGA and GRASS but come out of the same OSGEO foss4g stable.

You can use a stand-alone installer as linked by Darren Cope, or you can still use osgeo4w installer, but instead of opting for Express INstall, go to Advanced install and then when you are in there, expand the Desktop list and select only QGIS.  The installer will then prompt you for the essential dependencies.  Accept that and go ahead and install.  If you then want to add SAGA, GRASS or whatever afterwards, then you can go back into osgeo4w and, follow the same steps but now select SAGA or GRASS (you will see osgeo4w will mark QGIS now as 'keep'.. or offer you a newer version).  For a little very minor inconvenience for a minimum install, you get the great convenience of being able to easily add anything you didn't need initially at a later date or keep/check that your installation is up to date etc.

So, if I was maintaining many machines, possibly where some users are more/less advanced than others and want more stuff, I think I would go with osgeo4w and get familiar with customising an install via that route.  It's not at all difficult!

Comment: I don't think that the term "plugin" accurately describes the relationship between them...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed via OSGEO4W, which will by default install a 'package' of Open Source GIS applications. If you want to install only QGIS, try the Standalone Installer here: http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html